# Accessing a us-west-2 S3 bucket using Amazon Cognito and an IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

Amazon Cognito is only available in 2 zones: `us-east-1` and `eu-west-1`
I have a bucket in `us-west-2`

Here is the IAM policy I have for unauthenticated guests in my Cognito identity pool:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::vocal.test14/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

During uploading, I'm not able to access that S3 bucket
As stated here, it should be possible:

[image]

What rule do I need to add to my policy to give Cognito the ability to communicate with a bucket that's not in `us-east`?

---

Someone asked for more information, so here it is:

I've created a new bucket called `vocal.west2`
I've given the bucket the following CORS properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://domain.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://*.domain.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://domain.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://*.domain.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I've updated my IAM role to the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::vocal.west2/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm attempting to upload a file using the AWS JavaScript SDK. The code is pretty long, but here is the Cognito credential call:

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:REST-OF-ID-HERE'
});
```

Note that the region is set as 1us-east-1`, but that's because it's referencing the Cognito zone, not the S3 bucket.

Note also that the actual JS code that is doing the upload works fine when it's a `us-east-1` bucket.

Comment: Hello, would you be able to provide more information? Are you getting an accessDenied exception from S3? A code sample & the sdk you are using would be a good start in finding the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Resolved:**

I'm using the `AWS.S3.ManagedUpload` lib.
In order to specify the S3 zone, an `AWS.S3` object needs to be created (case matters here; doesn't work with `AWS.s3`)

Here is the `AWS.S3` object instantiation:

```
var s3 = (new AWS.S3({
    region: 'us-west-2'
}))
```

Here is the `AWS.S3.ManagedUpload` instantiation:

```
var upload = (new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
    params: {
        Bucket: 'vocal.test14',
        Key: 'filename',
        Body: file,
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
        ACL: 'public-read'
    },
    service: s3
}));
```

And here is the logic to upload/report progress:

```
upload.on('httpUploadProgress', function(event) {
    console.log(
        'Progress:',
        event.loaded,
        '/',
        event.total
    );
});
upload.send(function(err, data) {
    if (data) {
        console.log('Uploaded');
        console.log(data);
    } else {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
});
```

Thanks @mark-mercurio for your help

Answer (score 2):

I see you set the region to us-east-1 (to hit Amazon Cognito's endpoint).

When you instantiate the S3 client, try specifying the region.

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({region: 'us-west-2'});
```

Also, if this does not work, could you provide the error you are getting?

-Mark

Comment: Thanks for the tip Mark. There's a typo in that, and something else that needs to be done, but you got my on the right track. Thanks for your help. Going to post the answer shortly.